# RealTime обновление markdowm

Tags: vue.js, markdown

Всем привет, пытаюсь сделать бесшовный markdown редактор, как в dropbox paper.
То есть ты начал вводить markdown, а он автоматически меняется и ты продолжаешь его редактировать. В dropbox paper точь-в-точь как нужно.
Использую vuejs3, пытался использовать через div contenteditable и watch, привязывая событие @input к обновлению, то есть если сработал @input - мы перевели весь написанный текст в markdown и вернули в contenteditable div, но фокус постоянно пропадает и способ этот явно не самый рабочий.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь

```js
<template>

<div contenteditable=""
     :value='message'
     v-html="message"
     @input="controlContent"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Test",

  data() {
    return {
      message: "",
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    controlContent(e) {
      let markdown = require('markdown-it')
      let md = new markdown()
      let result = md.render(e.target.innerText)
      this.message = result
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Код сверху - простая копия того, что я пытаюсь сделать

Comment: Тут в принципе это единственный вариант через `contenteditable`, иначе никак. Я делал мини-редактор по типу как у ВК, нужно было чистить контент от любых тегов наоборот. По сути действие то же самое. Сброса фокуса у меня не было, но постоянно курсор перемещался в начало (решал через selectAll + `getSelection().collapseToEnd()`). Watch как таковой не нужен, достаточно @input и @change. Приведите код, чтобы можно было понять, что делаете так или не так.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, код приложил, попробовал сделать, как Вы сказали, но он перезаписывает данные

Comment: Перезаписывает данные, потому что Вы скармливаете рендереру чисто текст (`e.target.innerText`), который превращается в  HTML, а затем при повторной подстановке уже очищается самим JS (`e.target.innerText` снова возвращает чистый текст без HTML). Надо передавать `e.target.innerHTML`, но для этого поищите парсер, который работает в смешанном варианте (markdown-it только чистый текст будет преобразовывать)